# Angular forms with observable

Tags: angular

I got Error : Invalid event target on my script i did that before with @ViewChild without any issue but when i try to use FormGroup i got error!!

```
import { Component , OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup,FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
template: `<h1>Hello World!</h1>
            <form [formGroup]="frm1">
            <input type="text" formControlName="name" >
            <input type="text" formControlName="family" #family>
            </form>
            `,

})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{ 

 frm1 : FormGroup;

constructor( fb:FormBuilder){
    this.frm1 = fb.group({
        name : [],
        family: []
    });     
}
ngOnInit(){ 
    var keyup =  Observable.fromEvent(this.frm1.get('family').value , "keyup")
              .map((data:string) => data.replace(' ','-'))
              .debounceTime(400);               
    keyup.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter to `Observable.fromEvent` needs to be an HTMLElement (object), not its value (string).

But you really don't need to create observable manually since FormControl already provides you `valueChanges` which is EventEmmitter. So you just need to do something like this:

```javascript
ngOnInit() {
  var keyup = this.frm1.get('family').valueChanges
            .map((data:string) => data.replace(' ','-'))
            .debounceTime(400);               
  keyup.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
}
```

Comment: I did that before by remove value and got error : Argument of type 'AbstractControl' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventTargetLike'.
  Type 'AbstractControl' is not assignable to type 'HTMLCollection'.
    Property 'namedItem' is missing in type 'AbstractControl'.

Comment: Actually I would not do this anyway. You could get HTMLFormElement by local variable reference, but better to just use `valueChanges`. Check my updated answer. Much simpler.

Comment: I did that as you wrote but now i got new error: this.frm1.get(...).valueChanges.map is not a function

Comment: Make sure to import map operator: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'`. Similar to debounceTime: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime'`.

Comment: take a look on my script `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';`

Comment: `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx'` doesn't import `map` and `debounceTime`. You need to import them separately.